# How to manage variable state in singleton class?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, c++14

I am trying to make an application logger program in C++ for Linux/UNIX environment which handles the multi-thread environment efficently. The problem I am currently facing is related to singleton class, allow me show you the code first and then I will ask for the Q which I have digging from last few days-

```
class Logger {

private:
  int mNumber;


public:
  static Logger& getInstance(int num){

     static Logger object;

     /* 
       I have already solved the problem for single threaded application, below is what I was doing
     */   
     object.setNumber(num);

     /*
       But I can not do the above in multi thread application, even with lock( I prefer pthread) mutexes and semaphores.
     */
     return object;
  }

  void debug(const char* str){
     std::cout << "Num : "  << mNumber << " :: Message : " << str << std::endl;
  }

private:

  void setNumber(const int num){
    this->mNumber = value;
  }  
};  

#define logMe   Logger::getInstance(__LINE__)

void* threadOne(void* args){

   while(true){
      logMe.debug("I am from threadOne");
   }
   return (void*) nullptr;
}// end

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    logMe.debug("Works with single threaded application.");
   /*
     1) Correct me if I am wrong, the above gets expand to
        Logger::getInstance(__LINE__).debug("value");
     2) Now that is the problem, somehow, I want this value to pass to debug method. 
   */

   // This is what I have been trying to do-
   pthread_t tid;
   pthread_create(&tid, nullptr, threadOne, nullptr);

   while (true){
      logMe.debug("I am from Main");
      usleep(2000);     // This is not neccesarry just to check while debugging.
   }
   exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}// end
```

## The issue:

Somehow, I want to keep the record of line number and message at the same time.
  I am not sure if there are other patterns which can save my life. Any help in any direction would really be helpful. THANK YOU in advance.

Comment: How about `#define logMe(s) Logger::getInstance().debug(__LINE__, s)` and have debug take the line number as a parameter?

Comment: Im not discussing if this is the best, or even, the correct method of doing log, but to solve your problem, just call Log as `logMe("I am from Main");`  and define `logMe` as: `#define logMe(x) Logger::getInstance(__LINE__).debug(std::string((x)) + __LINE__)`, or something similar

Comment: Method parameter remained the option from starting. But lets say, it gives power to user for explicitly changing the parameter value. You know what I mean. @Eljay

Comment: Let me check @Amadeus. Thank you.

Comment: I guess not, I have also overload <<. So, they can do this `"logMe << "I am from main" << std::endl; `@Amadeus

Comment: @SunnySingh So, instead of calling `logMe`, call it `logDebug`

Comment: Just that you're aware of it, singleton is considered an antipattern by many. However, this isn't really your problem, because any kind of sharing of the logger would give you similar issues. Consider studying a few other libraries that do logging. As a general advise for new users here, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Separate the class that does the work from the class that holds the value:

```
struct Logger {
  struct Line {
    Logger &log;
    int n;
    void debug(const char *s)
    {log.debug(n,s);}
  };

  Line at(int n) {return {*this,n};}

private:
  void debug(int n,const char *s)
  {std::cout << "Num : "  << n << " :: Message : " << s << std::endl;}
};
```

You can make `Logger` a friend of `Line` to avoid exposing a constructible helper, but anyone can pass anything to `at` anyway.

Note here that `Logger::debug` doesn’t use `this`; if that’s true in the real case, make it `static` (or not a member function at all) and you can simplify `Line` and avoid a singleton, which is a major win (especially in a multithreaded environment).